# get and set methods from an ArrayList in another class

Tags: arraylist, get, set

```
/*
 * Notes here
 */
package billboardsign;

/**
 *
 * @author John Parada
 */
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Billboard 
{
    private String text;
    private ArrayList<String> messages = new ArrayList<String>();

    public Billboard()

    {
        messages.add("Happy New Year");
        messages.add("Happy Holidays");
        messages.add("Team Pizza");
        messages.add("Game On");
        messages.add("Let's Go Team");
    }

public ArrayList<String> getMessages()
{
    return messages;
}
public void setMessages(String msg)
{
    messages.add(msg);
}
public boolean isEmpty()
{
    return text == null || text.isEmpty();
}
public String substring(int begin, int end)
{
    if (begin >= 0 && end < text.length())
    {
        return text.substring(begin, end);
    }
    else
        return null;
}



//add the method Reverse here    
// THIS CODE IS NO GOOD!for (int count = text.length() - 1; count >= 0; count-- )
        //FOLLOW UP LINE System.out.printf( "%s ", text.charAt( count ) );
public String reverse()
{
    if (isEmpty())
        return null;
    else
    {
        char[] chars = text.toCharArray();

        //create antoher arrayList
        char[] reverse = new char[chars.length];

        for (int i = chars.length - 1, j = 0; i < 0; i--, j++)
        {
        reverse[j] = chars[i];
        }
    return new String(reverse);

    }
}

//add the method Replace string here
public String replace(char oldChar, char newChar)
{
return text.replace(oldChar, newChar);
}

//add the method displayInfo here
public void displayInfo()
{
    System.out.printf("\n%s\nMessage", messages);

}


}







/*
 * Notes on the Billboard Project
 */
package billboardsign;

/**
 *
 * @author John Parada
 */
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BillboardSign 
{

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) 
{

    Billboard newBillboard = new Billboard(); //default constructor


    //Menu 
    int choose_again = 1;
    int choiceNumber;
    Scanner newInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (choose_again > 0 )
    {
        //list options to user
        System.out.println ("\nPlease choose a number between 1 and 6 to choose an\n"
            + "option for the Messages Board to display: "
            + "\n1) Display Default Message 1"
            + "\n2) Display Default Message 2"
            + "\n3) Display Default Message 3"
            + "\n4) Display Default Message 4"
            + "\n5) Display Default Message 5"
            + "\n6) Enter a New Message"
            + "\n7) Reverse a Message"
            + "\n8) Replace a Message - Substring"
            + "\n9)  Exit Program");

        //get the user to input a selection 
        System.out.print ("\nPlease Enter Your Selection: ");
        choiceNumber = newInput.nextInt();

        //use switch statement to help with thieir choice input
        switch (choiceNumber)
            {   
                case 1:
                    //execute get() and displayInfo() method for default Message 1
                    //newBillboard = Billboard();
                    messages.get(0);
                    displayInfo();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    //execute get() and displayInfo() method for default Message 2
                    newBillboard = Billboard();
                    Billboard = displayInfo();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    //execute get() and displayInfo() method for default Message 3
                    newBillboard = Billboard();
                    Billboard = displayInfo();
                    break;
                case 4:
                    //execute get() and displayInfo() method for default Message 4
                    newBillboard = Billboard();
                    Billboard = displayInfo();
                    break;
                case 5:

                    displayInfo();
                    break;
                case 6:
                    //execute set() and displayInfo() methods to create a new message
                    break;
                case 7:
                    //execute reverse message method 
                    break;
                case 8:
                    //execute Replace message - Substring method
                case 9:
                    //Dispaly to the user that they have chose to exit 
                    System.out.print ("\nYou have chosen to cancel and exit. \n");
                    System.exit(0);
            }




        //prompt user for antother selection? (Contiune=1 and Exit= -1)
        System.out.println();
        System.out.print ("\nIf you would like to select another animal enter 1 or if your are done enter -1: ");
        choose_again = newInput.nextInt();
    }

}

private static void displayInfo() {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
}
}
```

In short, when the user selects 1, he or she is supposed to get the first element of the ArrayList(0). When he or she selects 2, they will get the second element in the ArrayList(1). I need to invoke the get method, and use the displayInfo of the Billboard.

Thank you in advance for any and all help.

Regards,

John Parada

Answer (score 0):

do something likewise,

```
case 1:
   newBillboard.getMessages().get(0);
   ...
case 1:
   newBillboard.getMessages().get(1);
....
And so on.
```

Answer (score 0):

your getMessages() method is returning an arraylist so either you should have in an arraylist variable in your main class like this

```
ArrayList<String> messages = newBillboard.getMessages();
```

and then call it like this

```
case 1:
                    //execute get() and displayInfo() method for default Message 1
                    //newBillboard = Billboard();
                    System.out.println (messages.get(0));
                    //displayInfo();
                    break;
```

or you can simply call it like this

```
newBillboard.getMessages.get(0);//here 0 is for first element
```

and there is no need to get an object of your class in every case
and what is the need of `displayInfo` is unclear so if you tell why have you added that i might see to it.